# Does Ruby on Rails ActiveRecordStore work with load balancing across servers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We are currently testing load balancing with pfsense and I am looking at what will happen to a rails session if the original server a user is connected to goes down. Is there a way to sync ActiveRecordStore data between servers or would something like SQLSessionStore be the best bet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Ruby on Rails supports multiple SessionStore backends, by default it uses a cookie-based one. But you can also keep the session in your database if you like.

The related documentation hs here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SessionStore.html

After you have set up a ActiveRecord model to be used as SessionStore you then configure your rails app to a different SessionStore through:

```
config.action_controller.session_store = :active_record_store
```

I have to admit that I haven't tried this out in any of my projects so far, but you should be able to figure it out by trying it out :)